# aircrack-ng on Raspberry pi 3 and WiFi adapter

Tags: wifi, kali-linux, aircrack-ng, raspberry-pi

I am just getting into ethical hacking and cybersecurity and would like some advice regarding USB Wi-Fi adapter. I am hacking on Raspberry PI 3 which is running Kali Linux. Furthermore, I have been following this video [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WfYxrLaqlN8&ab_channel=DavidBombal)
and been learning about aircrack-ng hacking tool.

What I am confused about, is whether I need the Wi-Fi adapter or not. Since I can start the wlan0mon with the command `airmon-ng start wlan0` and the interface, wlan0mon with monitor mode will appear when I check with `iwconfig`.

I have tried to proceed with the tutorial, but it does not seem to work properly. For example, I found the clients connected to my home access point with the command : `airodump-ng wlan0mon -b "MAC_ADDRESS"` and it says that there are no clients connected even though I have multiple devices connected to it.

To summarize, my questions are:

1. Do I need a Wi-Fi adapter for the Raspberry PI 3 even though I have access to wlan0mon?
2. If my home router is set up for both 2.4g and 5g and all client devices are connected to 5g, 2.4g USB adapters would be useless is that right? For example, adapter such as
   [AWUS036NHA](https://www.alfa.com.tw/products/awus036nha?variant=36473966166088) won't be able to monitor everything is that true?

Comment: You should be able to use the onboard WiFi if you use [patched drivers](https://github.com/seemoo-lab/nexmon). It doesn't look like injection is working, but you should still be able to capture traffic/handshakes.

Answer (score 0):

## Yes, you need Wi-Fi harrdware to capture packets.

Without it, you can't capture any packets. Just because you have a steering wheel doesn't mean you can actually drive - you need the rest of the car too.

## 2.4 GHz hardware can't monitor 5 GHz traffic

You need a 5 GHz compatible Wi-Fi hardware to monitor 5 GHz traffic. Else, you'll only be able to monitor 2.4 GHz traffic. However, 5 GHz is not fundamentally different than 2.4 GHz. You can simply create a 2.4 GHz hotspot and connect your device there.

Comment: Understood. Thank you very much. I think if I am going to play around with the WiFi hacks, I better off buy adapter that is capable of 2.4Ghz and 5Ghz. Maybe you used some yourself and could recommend a particular brand?

Comment: For example: https://www.alfa.com.tw/products/awus036ac?variant=36473965838408